# How do I pass an argument to a module function inside a module function in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, module

i am trying to update my shiny app by using modules. I still have some issues with it. Can somenone please help. Following is my code.

First I read my data in and create an Event Log

```
data <- read.csv2(file = "Data/FX_test.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings=c(""))

df_use <- data

df_use$Timestamp = as.POSIXct(df_use$Timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

#Create Event Log
events <- bupaR::activities_to_eventlog(
    df_use,
    case_id = 'Case.ID',
    activity_id = 'Activity',
    resource_id = 'User',
    timestamp = c('Timestamp', 'Timestamp')
)
```

then I create an UI and a Server for my dateRangeInput

```
dateRangeUI <- function(id){
    ns <- NS(id)
    dateRangeInput(ns("time"), h5(strong(em("DATE RANGE"))), start = as.Date(min(substr(df_use$Timestamp,0,10))),
                   min = as.Date(min(substr(df_use$Timestamp,0,10))), max = as.Date(max(substr(df_use$Timestamp,0,10))), end = as.Date(max(substr(df_use$Timestamp,0,10))))
    
}

dateRangeServer <- function(id){
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
        return(list(time = reactive({input$time})))
    })
}
```

Another module with UI and Server, output is a Processmap. **Here I want the data to be an argument in the function.**

```
prUI <- function(id){
    ns <- NS(id)
    grVizOutput(ns("Pr_map"))
}

prServer <- function(id, my_events){                      ### my_events 
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
        output$Pr_map <- renderGrViz({
            my_events %>% process_map(type_edges = frequency("relative_case"))
        })
    })
}
```

Now the UI and Server for buttons. **Here i want to call the above module and pass the updated data to the function.**

```
actionButtonUI <- function(id){
    ns <- NS(id)
    actionButton(ns("PLOT"), label = "PLOT", style = "color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7;border-color: #2e6da4")
}

actionButtonServer <- function(id, input_time, pr){
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
        observeEvent(input$PLOT, {
            print("Button Check") 
            
            time <- input_time$time()
            
            events_Filtered <- filter_time_period(events, interval = ymd(c(time[1]+1, time[2]+1)), filter_method = "complete")
            
            pr(events_Filtered)  # I want this to work        
        })   
    })      
}
```

And the final UI and Server that puts all together.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    dateRangeUI("time"),
    actionButtonUI('button1'),
    prUI("PR_map")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    input_time = dateRangeServer('time')
    pr = prServer('PR_map', **### what to put in here ###**)
    
    actionButtonServer('button1', input_time, pr)

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: "output is a Processmap".  No, it isn't.  The server function returns `NULL`.